# Is $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ dense on $C^0(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, sobolev-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Prove:

(1) $W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is the set of all lipschitz functions on $\Omega$.

(2)$W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense on $C^0(\Omega)$

$\Omega\in\mathbb R^k$ is an open, convex set.

(Not homeworks)

---

I believe that the state (1) is not correct. We can only prove that a function $f\in W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb R)$ coincide almost everywhere with a Lipschitz continuous function. But how to show this?

For (2) I believe it is right? On wikipedia it says that "all L-continuous" function on a compact metric space is a subalgebra of Banach space of continuous functions, and thus dense in it. But how to show this for an open, convex set $\Omega$?

Comment: Let $\Omega = \{ |x| < 1\}$. If $f \in C^0(\Omega)$ then look at $f_\epsilon(x) = C\epsilon^{-k} \int_{|y| < \epsilon} f(\frac{x-y}{1+\epsilon})dy $ where $\frac{1}{C} = \int_{|x| < 1} dx$

Comment: thhis is worth https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638433/density-of-lipschitz-functions-in-the-set-of-uniformly-continuous-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may object to (1) on the ground that $W^{1,\infty}$ is not a set of functions, but a set of equivalence classes of functions. But I think this would be arguing about a technicality. Each equivalence class in $W^{1,\infty}$ contains a Lipschitz continuous representative, and it is natural to identify the class with this representative.

Details: let $f\in W^{1,\infty}(\Omega)$. On almost every line segment parallel to a coordinate axis, $f$ is absolutely continuous with derivative in $L^\infty$; but this means it is Lipschitz continuous. Let $A$ be the union of all such line segments contained in $\Omega$. Then $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $A$, and $\Omega\setminus A$ has measure zero. So if we  redefine $f$ on $\Omega\setminus A$, extending $f$ by continuity, the result is a Lipschitz continuous function on $\Omega$.

---

(2) requires one to specify a topology on $C^0(\Omega)$; I suppose it's the topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets. If we tried uniform norm, then it would be necessary to restrict attention to bounded functions; however, density would fail anyway.

First, approximate $f\in C^0(\Omega)$ by compactly supported functions $f_n\in C^0_c(\Omega)$; for this it suffices to take $f_n= f\chi_n$ where $\chi_n$ is a cut-off function that is equal to $1$ on most of $\Omega$ and has compact support.

Second, approximate $f_n$ by 
$$g_L(x) = \sup_{y\in \Omega} (f_n(y) - L|x-y|) \tag1$$
Note that $g_L$ is $L$-Lipschitz and $g_L\ge f_n$. Also, if $L$ is large enough then $g_L\le f_n+\epsilon$ by virtue of the uniform continuity of $f_n$. Specifically, the supremum in (1) is effectively taken only over $|x-y|<\delta$, as larger values of $|x-y|$ incur too much   penalty from $- L|x-y|$.

Comment: It is not clear to me what is supposed to be $\sup_{y\in \Omega} (f_n(y) - L|x-y|)$. Why not use a convolution ? (if $f$ is not uniformly continuous, use a different mollifier on each compact)

Comment: Sup- and inf-convolutions are useful too, in particular when there is no canonical measure. There is one here, but the statement and this proof generalize to arbitrary metric spaces (with Heine Borel property).

Comment: So you meant for $f$ non-negative and $L$ very large $\sup_{y\in \Omega} (f_n(y) - L|x-y|) $ approximates $f$. Anyway convolution is easier to understand.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2638433/density-of-lipschitz-functions-in-the-set-of-uniformly-continuous-functions?noredirect=1&lq=1