# Density of Lipschitz functions in the set of uniformly continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity, lipschitz-functions

Let $(E,d)$ be a compact metric space  we consider the sup distance

$$d_\infty(f,g) = \sup_{x\in E}d(f(x),g(x))$$

In the exercise it is asked to  prove that $(Lip(E), d_\infty$) set of  Lipschitz functions on $(E,d)$ is dense in $(Uc(E), d_\infty$) set of  uniformly continuous functions on $(E,d)$.

> Moreover  for given $f:E\to \Bbb R$ then construct an explicit sequence $(f_j)_j$ of Lipschitz functions converging uniformly to $f$.

In fact this exercise to be corrected next week.

So I kindly ask for a hint or trick on how I can construct such sequence.

Comment: Have a look at the last paragraph in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2462337/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint/trick: take $$f_j(x)=\inf_{y\in E}\{f(y)+j\cdot d(x,y)\}.$$

$$f_j\overset{Uc}{\longrightarrow} f$$

Comment: What if $E$ is infinite? You will surely need compactness.

Comment: @Math_QED: I don't know what your point is. I have not assumed $E$ is finite.

Comment: So you take the minimum of an infinite amount of things? How is that well defined?

Comment: @Math_QED E is compact. and if you don't like put the inf it works as well

Comment: Yes I know how to fix it. But as written it was incorrect

Comment: @Math_QED: no, it is a misunderstanding to think you can only take the $\min$ of a finite set. If a set has a minimum, you can refer to it using the "$\min$" operator. The minimum of a continuous function over a compact set always exists.

Comment: Ah yes I missed that. My bad!